# Custom post type routing with hierarchy

Tags: custom-post-types, hierarchical, routing

I've been playing around with a lot of custom post types lately and I am pretty anal about my URL structure / routing.

An issue I ran in to a with a site that I just developed was this:

- I had many custom post types, for example: `videos`
- The URL structure to 'view' the video list (ie: archive of sorts) was `/media/videos/`
- This 'view' was basically a custom `WP_Query` displaying things properly from a custom .php template.
- When an individual 'video' link is clicked you are taken to the post type URL structure, ie: `www.site.com/videos/{slug}`
- This causes all loss of URL structure/parental relationship to structure.

I would love to solve this problem:

- When you navigate to `/media/videos/` you get the custom loaded template file
- When you click a video `permalink()`, you will be linked to `/media/videos/{slug}`
- Ideally this would perserve hierarchy of URL structure (so if something like Breadcrumb NavXT it would still have a relationship).

I made a teacher/student/etc module one time where I did custom routing via `add_rewrite_rule` to handle these problems, but I would rather figure out how to handle hierarchy appropriately in this situation.

Can someone please point me in to the right direction?

Thanks!

Tre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare the custom post type, there is a parameter "rewrite" where you declare the slug for the post type. Change the slug to "media/videos", and then visit your Settings > Permalinks page to update your rewrite rules.

```
register_post_type( 'videos',
    array('labels' => array(),
        'rewrite'   => array( 'slug' => 'media/videos', 'with_front' => false )
    )
);
```

Comment: If I have a page called `media/videos` this will cause a permalink collision, correct? That's ideally what I'd want. `media/videos` => page & `media/videos/{slug}` => actual post type. I tried using 'slug' & 'with_front' => false, and I got collision

Comment: I don't have that problem. I defined the slug for the post type as 'media/videos' and then I created a top-level page with slug 'media' and child page with slug 'videos'. When I access 'media/videos', I get the page. When I access a video at 'media/videos/video-slug', I get the video with slug 'video-slug'.

Comment: Make sure you visit the permalinks page? :(

Comment: Hm. I'll have to take a look at this again. Did you create the post type before the pages? Though that shouldn't matter.

Comment: Looks like that worked! Odd. I must have done something completely wrong yesterday. Thanks!

Comment: Now I wish there was a way for me to make it a parent of a page without breaking everything :)

Comment: Not sure about that... glad you got the first part working.